# Footer moves up from bottom of page in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, sticky-footer

I am working on an MVC site and I am having trouble getting the footer to stay at the bottom of the page in IE10. For some reason it will appear at the bottom of the window originally when the page is loaded but then it will stay in the same position even when you scroll down and hence the footer is no longer at the bottom of the page.

What is strange is that when you resize the window the footer is then fixed at the bottom of the page.When you return the page to full size the footer is still fixed at the bottom of the page. If you refresh the page or go to a new page the footer is then no longer fixed at the bottom of the page.

I have tried a few CSS solutions to create a Sticky Footer and they have worked in Firefox,Chrome and all the older IE's but not IE10. I have tried [ryanfait's solution](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) and [cssstickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) but neither have worked for me.

I have the following CSS code for my footer currently:

```
#footer{background:#098a9d url(../img/headFootShadow.png) repeat-x 0 -8px;padding:20px 0 0;display:block;height:65px;margin-top:30px;color:#fff}
#footer a{color:#FFF;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none}
#footer a:hover{text-decoration:underline}

/*Sticky footer hack*/

html, body {height: 100%;}
html#lightbox{height:auto;}
#fullWrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto;padding-bottom:105px;}  /* must be same height as the footer*/
#footer {position: relative;margin-top: -85px; /* negative value of footer height  */height:65px;clear:both}
```

As I said this works perfectly for Chrome,Firefox and the older IE's but not IE10. Would anyone know how to fix this or a possible workaround that would work? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Bernard